# Passing a Javascript Variable to Android Activity?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

Basically I want get data I already have accessed from javascript and passing it to Java/Android so that I can work with it there.

```
     /* An instance of this class will be registered as a JavaScript interface */
    class MyJavaScriptInterface {


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void setX(String html){
            Activity.this.x = html;
            Toast.makeText(myApp, Activity.this.x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

this works but I want to be able to call the same Toast line anywhere and get the same result. Currently it only returns null/empty when not called through loading through webview.loadUrl("Javascript:"...

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access stored javascript variables, you must do it through a function call.
You have to call it from javascript in your html page, for example:

```
TheNameOfYourInterface.setX('value');
```

TheNameOfYourInterface will be a javascript object when you add the interface to the webview via

```
YourWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(),"TheNameOfYourInterface");
```

so you can do the logic on your webview and call the interface when you set the data so the method in the Java side will be called.

Comment: I'm kinda sad to say that you are right. This seems to be the only way to pass back any sort of JS information to the activity.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different solution to what I need, and I feel like it works for all who do not need get a value calc'd by javascript. My solution to my need was to HTTP GET the html/javascript and then parse it as a string. It saves me some time by not needing to load X WebViews and then (re)creating all my functions in the JavaScript Interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be a good idea to store the HTML in Shared Preferences ,which is a form of persistent storage.This way you will be able to access it from anywhere.

```
   //------get sharedPreferences

SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//--------modify the value

pref.edit().putString("ToastString", html).commit();

//-------get a value from this from anywhere

String toastValue=pref.getString("ToastString", "");
```

Comment: I tried to implement this and it doesn't seem to work. There seem to be 2 seperate vars with the same name going on 1) in  JavaScriptInterface that actually is set and the other in the main activity that stays null.