# Download file to Android from ashx call

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an Android web app.

There is a button on that aspx page.

It invokes a Jquery ajax call to my code behind web method.

This method finds the location of a video file.

This file location is then return as part of the url for an ashx call.

So for instance, the web method finds the video file and returns a string to the ajax call in this format:

```
www.myserver.com?GetThisFile=MyLocationOfNewlyCreatedVideoFile.ashx.
```

Then in the success event of the Ajax call I do this:

```
event.preventDefault();
window.location = 'http://www.myserver.com?GetThisFile=Mylocationof newlycreatedvideofile.ashx';
```

If I call this via a browser on a desktop it works.
If I do this via web browser in Android is does not work.

There is an SD card in the Android device.

Is it possible to download a file in Android using this method?

If not is it possible to download a file using a button? For instance I just a have a button that points like this:

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#btnDownloadReady").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.location = 'http://MyUrl/File.mp4';
        });
    });
```

But it attempts to play the file.  I just want it saved to the SD card. (I know mp4 will not play on Android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be possible without a server side scripting (Java) because according to the sequence of commands displayed in jQuery, it seems like you want to open the file in your Android app. Desktop browsers automatically know where to save the file because browsers were configured to do this. However, with Android, because you have your own web view, you would need to create a java program to save a full file to save in a directory or music directory properly using the [Download Manager for Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

Comment: Hi,that informs me quite a lot and is very useful. But, is the download manager accessible via jquery/web app?  If not is it possible to save the image as a byte stream and use jquery to save as file to SD?

Comment: Android APIs such as download manager can only be implemented using Java. You may need write a JavaScript code to communicate with Android through Activity Intents, wherein Android Download Manager API can catch it from an Intent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287820/passing-a-javascript-variable-to-android-activity