# Android WebView extract HTML

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

Basically, I am developing an Android Application where the user can access the HTML Content of the Page and choose what to do with it next whether it be write to the File System , Upload Via FTP etc.. the user cannot see the HTML but it stores it for viewing later.

I have tried adding a JavaScript interface then adding it to the onPageFinished Event, it just doesnt want to hand over the HTML, heres what I did:

so for my onPageFinished event:

```
Webview wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webbrowser);
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JSEngine() , "JSEngine");
  public void onPageFinished(WebView wv , String html){
   //code to execute
   wv.loadUrl("javascript: window.JSEngine.processHTML(document.body.innerHTML)");
  }
```

the code to execute inside the processHTML cant be shared for certain reasons but i can tell you that the html variable is empty.

then my javascript interface:

```
Class JSEngine{
  @JavascriptInterface
  public void processHTML(String html){
    //code to execute
    //html variable is null
  }
}
```

Is there anything that can tackle my problem? All of my permissions are set, my class is working perfectly until it comes to The webview handing over the html.

Comment: `"javascript: window.JSEngine.processHTML(document.body.innerHTML)"` is it valid?

Comment: yes it works when I test it on a regular web browser

Comment: check here if you missed anything  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287820/passing-a-javascript-variable-to-android-activity

Comment: I have everything , its just not returning the HTML , because the lack of functionality that comes with WebView , Im looking into other Alternatives

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't need to see the HTML, then forget about `WebView`, open the page with a regular HTTP stream, read the HTML data and work with that.

I suspect that there is actually is a preview of the web page, in which case your best bet is to read the HTML data stream, then turn around and display in in the `WebView` with `loadDataWithBaseURL()`.

Another possibility might be to override `WebViewClient.onLoadResource()` and open an HTTP stream to read the data on that URL.  This is redundant, since the `WebView` is going to read the data itself, but the problem is that `WebView` just doesn't give you hooks into the HTTP data stream it is reading.

Comment: Yes but I need javascript to come into place as well i need it to execute like a basic browser

Comment: that is a really good idea, as i have already thought of that , thanks for the answer though , it would be correct if it executed javascript on the HTTP Stream

Comment: It depends on what data you are trying to save.  If you have the correct base URL in `loadDataWithBaseUrl()`, the javascript will be loaded by the `WebView` and run as you would expect once the HTML data is loaded.  The whole idea of the base URL is to handle same origin policy.

Comment: but i want the HTML to be changed by the Javascript before anything else is done with it , this is why i wanted to use webview it was (at the time) an easy solution to my problem but ive had more problems then anything with it, Im only going to use the WebView just to view the actual HTML now.