# Accessing js variable from android MainActivity

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I want to access a webapp as a android app, for this what I have done is simply calling url of that webapp by using webview. Webapp contains one js variable, I want to access that variable into androids MainActivity, how can I access and assign value to js variable which is in different webapp by using android MainActivity. Following is my code snippet for MainActivity,

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.mywebapp.com");

        setContentView(mWebview);


    }
```

My main question is how to access and assign a value to js variable through androids MainActivity which is in different app/html?

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287820/passing-a-javascript-variable-to-android-activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     // Call method in js or html
 Android.getImageUrl("text");

    // add this line in main activity.    
     webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

    // js value get in this method.(add this method in activity)
    public class JavaScriptInterface {
                Context mContext;

                JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                    mContext = c;
                }

                @JavascriptInterface
                public void getImageUrl(String text) {
        // js value get here.
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: where should I implement getImageUrl(); method ?

Comment: you can call this method in js or html

Comment: Yes I will call it from js/html, but where is getImageUrl() method definition is implemented? In mainActivity or somewhere else?
Should I have to implement it or not?? I am sorry asking very basic questions I am new to android.